# Can i retrieve an event that i have deleted?

Tags: civievent

I have deleted an event and would like to retrieve it back.  Is it possible to retrieve it?  Please advise how to do it. tks

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a (recent) backup of your site? That's what you'd need to restore.

Comment: In CiviCRM contacts and cases are trashed based on your configuration. Events are deleted and can not be retrieved. So, as @KarinG suggested, you need to revert to your backup.